# chroot 64 bit -> 32 bit = 'command not found'

Tags: linux, centos, chroot, environment-variables, 32bit-64bit

Very obviously 32 bit cannot chroot to 64 bit but I am confident that I have successfully chrooted from 64 bit to 32 bit using Gentoo but when I

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount /dev/vg_atom1/lv_root /mnt/lvm -o exec
[root@localhost ~]# mount -t proc proc /mnt/lvm/proc
[root@localhost ~]# mount --rbind /dev /mnt/lvm/dev
[root@localhost ~]# mount --rbind /sys /mnt/lvm/sys
[root@localhost ~]# chroot /mnt/lvm /bin/bash
bash: uname: command not found
[root@localhost /]# source /etc/profile
```

I get

```
bash: uname: command not found
[root@localhost /]# cp -L /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/lvm/etc/
bash: cp: command not found
[root@localhost /]# ls
bash: ls: command not found
[root@localhost /]# exit
exit
```

everything is 'command not found??'

env output:

```
[root@localhost /]# env
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=67.83.132.41 64275 22
QTDIR=/usr/lib/qt-3.3
QTINC=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/include
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
PATH=/sbin:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PWD=/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HOME=/root
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=root
QTLIB=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/lib
CVS_RSH=ssh
SSH_CONNECTION=67.83.132.41 64275 192.168.15.31 22
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Why are all my basic bash commands failing?

Comment: Please don't forget to ask your question ;)

Comment: Could it be possible that /mnt/lvm is empty?

Comment: @Sgaduuw no, /mnt/lvm is very much populated with my mounted logical volume, I can see all of the directories and files. also, the drive was connected to a 32 bit machine earlier and the exact same mount / disk access method was used and the command passwd was very much found, unlike now. I am assuming it is a 64 -> 32 issue since the host is brand spanking new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like /bin is missing from the PATH.

Comment: That was it!!!!!